# how I copy dictionary and return new one

Tags: python

So I need to make function that return reversed dictionary

this is what I tried:

```
def kaanna(sanakirja: dict):
    uusi = {}

    for avain, arvo in sanakirja.items():
        uusi[arvo] = avain

    print(uusi)

s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}

kaanna(s)

print(s)
```

But this only return this same s dictionary and its should retunr it like this {10:1, 20:2, 30:3 etc.}

Comment: @Barmar There is a `print(uusi)` inside the function.

Comment: The function doesn't modify the dictionary, it creates a new one and prints it.

Comment: Do a `return uusi` in the end of `kaanna`, and assign it somewhere. Or do you want to modify your `dict` in-place?

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse a KV pair in a dict with a [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/#examples).

```
s = {1: 10, 2: 20}
new_s = { v:k for k, v in s.items()}
print(new_s) # prints {10: 1, 20: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no return from `kaanna`, nor a reassignment of `s`. This would work as you expect

```py
def kaanna(sanakirja: dict):
    uusi = {}

    for avain, arvo in sanakirja.items():
        uusi[arvo] = avain

    return uusi

s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}

s = kaanna(s)
print(s)
```

However, you can simplify this by using dictionary comprehension like so

```py
s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}
s_reversed = {v: k for k,v in s.items()}

s_reversed
{10: 1, 20: 2, 30: 3, 40: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `print(s)`, you will see exactly the same dictionary as `s` was originally because none of your code modifies `s`. The `print(uusi)` shows the new dictionary you created. However, you say you want to return the dictionary, so you should change `print(uusi)` to `return uusi`. Then you can do something like `print(kaanna(s))` to see the new dict.

I suggest you read more about return.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the output of that function, Try below code

```
def kaanna(sanakirja: dict):

    uusi = {}

    for avain, arvo in sanakirja.items():
        uusi[arvo] = avain

    print(uusi)
    return uusi

s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}

s = kaanna(s)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely in a dict comprehension to avoid the need for a whole function (though other comments here are right, you forget to return the new dict at the end of your function)

```py
rev = {val: key for key, val in s.items()}
```

if there are multiple `val` with the same value then the last one in the original dict will have priority

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the newly generated dictionary (the reversed one), not the original one:

```
def kaanna(sanakirja: dict):
    uusi = {}

    for avain, arvo in sanakirja.items():
        uusi[arvo] = avain

    return(uusi)

s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}

new_s = kaanna(s)

print(new_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was close. "uusi" was only printing the reversed dictionary, not actually modifying the dictionary "s". You will then need to instead of just calling the function, set "s" equal to the function call.

```
def kaanna(sanakirja: dict):
uusi = {}

for avain, arvo in sanakirja.items():
    uusi[arvo] = avain

    return(uusi)

s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40}

s=kaanna(s)

print(s)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40} 

def kaanna(sanakirja: dict): 
    return dict(reversed(list(sanakirja.items())))

kaanna(s)
```

{4: 40, 3: 30, 2: 20, 1: 10}